# How to work with GeoServer and OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I am new to GeoServer and am a bit lost at the moment.

I have added shapefiles to GeoServer and created a layer containing all the shapefiles that I would like to display on my externally hosted web site.  When I go to `layer preview` in GeoServer it allows you to display an OpenLayers preview in a pop up. I have copied the page source from the preview into the HTML of my hosted web site. This seems to work fine when I open my web page when GeoServer is running.  As soon as I turn off GeoServer I can no longer view these data on my web page.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: leave Geoserver running...

Answer (score 5):

You pretty much answered the question yourself: Geoserver has to be running if you want to serve maps on your website. Every time the page is requested, Geoserver has to draw the map/image.

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse unless Geoserver running, your site can not the map images (tiles) from GeoServer - normally it requested through WMS calls. 
If there are any concerns on performance for running GeoServer and generate image on the fly, you could consider geowebcache configured, which will be caching all the tiles and respond back for future request. However not that in this case to Geoserver should be running stage. However no new images get generated as long as they in cache.

Comment: By using "older" solutions as tilecache which runs separately from Geoserver cached tiles could be served even if Geoserver is not running.

Comment: You can download tilecache from here - http://tilecache.org/.
It is also possible to seed all layers that you need and after that you will not need to have Geoserver running until you want to update data.